# Why does setting focus in the OnNavigatedTo() event not set focus?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've got this code in a pages OnNavigatedTo() event:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxGroupName.Text))
{
    textBoxGroupName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

...but textBoxGroupName does not have focus when the page displays. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnNavigatedTo` happens to early in the page lifetime for setting the focus to work. You should call your code in the `Loaded` event:

```
private void MainPage_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxGroupName.Text))
    {
        textBoxGroupName.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
}
```

Of course you need to setup the handler in your `.xaml` file (I've omitted the other attributes in the `Page` element:

```
<Page
    Loaded="MainPage_OnLoaded">
```

Answer (score 2):

Only controls that are contained within the GroupBox control can be selected or receive focus. Seems like you are not using GroupBox correctly.

#### From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx)

> The complete GroupBox itself cannot be selected or receive focus. For more information about how this control responds to the Focus and Select methods, see the following Control members: CanFocus, CanSelect, Focused, ContainsFocus, Focus, Select.

#### Hint:

You maybe want to use the [Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property to access the child controls:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxGroupName.Text))
{
    var child_TextBox = textBoxGroupName.Controls["myTextBox"]
    if(child_TextBox.CanFocus)
        child_TextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

Comment: I don't have a GroupBox - textBoxGroupName is contained within a Grid.